# Curly braces in my Java lstlisting are not shown

Tags: listings, brackets

I'm writing my thesis with ShareLatex online tool (pdfLaTeX compiler) based on template; [METU Thesis Template on ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/metu-template). When I try to add a *lstlisting* or *lstinputlisting* to my document, curly braces (*{*, *}*) in my **Java** code are not showing at all. I'm fairly new at LaTeX but I tried a lot of solutions found online like escaping brackets in my Java code, or trying to adjust *lstset* parameters accordingly. I also tried to simplify and comment out every *lstset* directive but nothing solved my problem.

In my tests, it seems that when I use *metu.cls* as my document class, it messes up with my listing formatting. How can I overcome this issue or include a different document class just for my listings?Thanks for any help.

A sample of my document (For compiling, I just included some parts of the template)
(For the document class directive, *metu.cls* file can be found in the following link - [metu.cls](http://www.filedropper.com/metu)):

```
%%%% Works fine with this default article document class %%%%
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%%%% When I use the "metu" class, it seems like it messes up with my source codes %%%%
\documentclass[chaparabic,ceng,ms,12pt,oneandhalf]{metu}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xy} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

% Listings formatting directives
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\lstset{float}
\makeatletter
\let\lst@floatdefault\lst@float
\makeatother
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf}}
\restylefloat{figure}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\definecolor{keyword}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{comment}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{string}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{splashedwhite}{rgb}{1.0, 0.99, 1.0}
\definecolor{reserved}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\lstset{
    language = Java,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=2,
    showspaces=false, 
    frame=single,
    breaklines=true,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    backgroundcolor=\color{splashedwhite},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{comment},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keyword},
    stringstyle=\color{string},
    extendedchars=true,
    captionpos=t
}

\begin{document}
% Sample lstlisting from my document
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Browsed Log Hadoop Mapper Code]
public void map(Text key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
List<String> logValues = Lists.newArrayList();

StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), LOG_SEPERATOR);
while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    logValues.add(itr.nextToken());
}

context.write(new Text(logValues.get(UID_INDEX)), new Text(logValues.get(URL_INDEX)));
}
\end{lstlisting}

% Sample lstinputlisting from my document
%\lstinputlisting[language=Java, float=false, frame=none]{source-codes/EUrlCategory.java}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for the heads up, I edited the question as you suggested and I hope it helps.

Comment: Good, but it's best to have the entire MWE in one code block (less editing required).

Comment: @Jubobs I found out that metu.cls document class file is my problem, however I need it because it is the main template document for my thesis. Can you help me to pinpoint the code that causes the problem? The class file can be found in the following link: http://www.filedropper.com/metu

Comment: That is not enough, `metu` need more files.

Comment: Besides, do you really need all those packages to show the error? See if you remove some of them, then we have less to worry about

Comment: Found it. It is this line inside `metu.cls`: ``\uccode`@=`I \lccode`@="10``, that messes up `listings` and the `{}` disappear. It is found at the very end. No idea what it is for.

Comment: Thank you very much @daleif commenting out that line solved the problem, and apparently it has not changed the overall looks of my document, however I will investigate it more and try to find out what it is for.. But also in metu.cls file, line 16 "\newif\ifpn@topr \pn@toprtrueT" directive is giving error: "Undefined control sequence.", do you have any idea what this is about? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry again my bad, "\newif\ifpn@topr \pn@toprtrueT" has a bogus char at the end which is "T" (I guess mistyped). When removed there are no errors given in the compile phase. @daleif if you like you can post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be seen with this very small MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\uccode`@=`I \lccode`@="10

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language = Java,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
... InterruptedException {

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The `` \uccode`@=`I \lccode`@="10 `` line is found at the very end of `metu.cls`, and it apparently messes up `listings`. Remove the line, and the `{}` reappear.